# admob ads not working in android air app

Tags: android, air, adobe, admob

This is the code i have used in adobe flash

```
var _stageWebView:StageWebView;
var myAdvertURL:String = "http://www.xxxxx.com/admob/admob.html";
//
createAd()
//
function createAd():void {
    // check that _stageWebView doersn't exist
    if (! _stageWebView) {
        _stageWebView = new StageWebView () ;
        // set the size of the html 'window'
        _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,800,50);
        // add a listener for when the content of the StageWebView changes
        //_stageWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE,onLocationChange);
        // start loading the URL;
        _stageWebView.loadURL(myAdvertURL);
    }
    // show the ad by setting it's stage property;
    _stageWebView.stage = stage;
}
```

This is the html code in admob.html

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
 pubid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 bgcolor: '000000', 
 text: 'ffffff', 
 ama: false,
 test: false
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
</body>
```

Can any one please guide me where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If you do, please add them to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this code might work,

```
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.Graphics;

var webAd:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webAd.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0,0,800,50);
webAd.stage = this.stage;

webAd.loadURL( "http://www.google.co.uk" );
```

Just replace Google.co.uk with your URL.